# Can I setup SSL on Azure for a regular Website? (Not WCF or MVC)

Tags: .net, ssl, azure, https

The question says it all: Can I setup SSL on Azure for a regular .net Website? (Not WCF or MVC)?

I see lots of articles telling me to update the service configuration file etc.  But I dont have those files on a regular website.

Comment: Duplicate of [SSL Certificate with Windows Azure Website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11766225/145173).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure Web Sites, SSL is currently not supported. Supposedly that's "coming soon" so unfortunately you'll have to wait.

Take a look at this post for more info:
[SSL Certificate with Windows Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766225/ssl-certificate-with-windows-azure-website)

Answer (score 1):

SSL with Custom Domains is now available in preview, as documented in the [Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/) overview. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16892150/145173) on a duplicate question for details about its status.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SSL on Azure Web Sites but you can use them on Web Roles within Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This SSL Forwarder can help until they properly support custom SSL certificates.

http://www.bradygaster.com/running-ssl-with-windows-azure-web-sites